# JGitInternalException ERROR Creating lock file Too many open files

Tags: jgit

I am using JGit for downloading repositories from gerrit (using cycle). There are more than 2000 repositories to download. A am getting error approximately on 1000 repo.

The is my method to download repo:

```
override fun downloadProject(moduleName: String): Path {
    val tempDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory(moduleName)
    val cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository()
    moduleInfoDao.getModuleByName(moduleName).codeRepository?.let {
        cloneCommand.setURI(makeSshUri(it))
    } ?: throw ModuleWithoutRepositoryException()
    cloneCommand.setTransportConfigCallback { transport ->
        val sshTransport = transport as SshTransport
        sshTransport.sshSessionFactory = sshSessionFactory
    }
    cloneCommand.setDirectory(tempDirectory.toFile())
    cloneCommand.setBare(false)
    val cloneResult = cloneCommand.call()

    cloneResult.close()
    cloneCommand?.repository?.close()

    return tempDirectory
}
```

The is the exception trace:

```
> 2022-09-24 19:26:15.941 [ool-request-processor-thread-1] ERROR Creating lock file /var/folders/6_/h619j3tx5fscmn4q2wr0vqth0000gp/T/module-agents-offline15007549319743888409/.git/HEAD.lock failed - <o.e.j.internal.storage.file.LockFile> - org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.LockFile.lock(LockFile.java:144) 
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/folders/6_/h619j3tx5fscmn4q2wr0vqth0000gp/T/module-agents-offline15007549319743888409/.git/HEAD.lock: Too many open files
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:375)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS_POSIX.createNewFileAtomic(FS_POSIX.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.LockFile.lock(LockFile.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.RefDirectoryUpdate.tryLock(RefDirectoryUpdate.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.RefUpdate.link(RefUpdate.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.create(FileRepository.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.InitCommand.call(InitCommand.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.init(CloneCommand.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:173)
    at ru.myorganization.payin.modules.quality.service.GitDownloaderService.downloadProject(GitDownloaderService.kt:48)
    at ru.myorganization.payin.modules.quality.service.ProjectDownloadingAbstractnessService.getAbstractnessFactor(ProjectDownloadingAbstractnessService.kt:15)
    at ru.myorganization.payin.modules.quality.service.StableAbstractionsPrincipleService.getWarnings(StableAbstractionsPrincipleService.kt:25)
    at ru.myorganization.payin.modules.quality.service.StableAbstractionsPrincipleService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$787d1f0a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(CacheInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:421)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at ru.myorganization.payin.modules.quality.service.StableAbstractionsPrincipleService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42c48c58.getWarnings(<generated>)
    at ru.myorganization.payin.modules.quality.service.WarningsCompositeService.getWarnings(WarningsCompositeService.kt:19)
    at ru.myorganization.payin.modules.quality.controllers.scheduler.FindModuleWarningsScheduler.setWarnings(FindModuleWarningsScheduler.kt:43)
    at ru.myorganization.payin.modules.quality.controllers.scheduler.FindModuleWarningsScheduler.analyzeAllModules(FindModuleWarningsScheduler.kt:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your OS is running out of file-handles.

Make sure to `close()` any file-based resources that are opened in your application.

The problem can also be somewhere else in your code!

You might want to make use of https://github.com/jenkinsci/lib-file-leak-detector to find out which file-handles are leaking in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was on using other library that create a lot of files and dont close the resourses